# Assign a value using Least()

Tags: mysql, variables, set

I am using a loop inside of a trigger to update hierarchical relationships in a MySQL database. Tables are INNO.

What I have is:

```
SET vDateCounter = NEW.DateTime;
```

The trouble is that this only works one-half of the time. If an UPDATE includes a more recent DateTime, my loop begins but it does not reprocess the OLD.DateTime, nor any events between the OLD.DateTime and the NEW.DateTime.

For example, if I change '2015-04-20 06:00:00' to '2015-04-20 18:00:00', I want my update loop to always begin with the LEAST of the two dateTimes.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
SET vDateCounter = (SELECT LEAST(OLD.DateTime, NEW.DateTime));
```

Any thoughts on best approach?

Comment: Yes the least should work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a function and call from your trigger.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Least] 
(
@date1 datetime,
@date2 datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @vDateCounter  datetime

 SELECT @vDateCounter= min(dateLeast)  
 FROM ( 
      SELECT @date1 AS dateLeast
      UNION ALL
      SELECT @date2 AS dateLeast
      ) AS dates
      RETURN @vDateCounter
END
```

In your trigger, select it.

```
SELECT dbo.FN_Least('2015-04-21 06:00:00','2015-04-20 18:00:00')
```